# Have Movie Player always stay on-top of other windows

Tags: totem, window-management

Is there a way to make the movie player to stay on-top while switching windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. in order to keep any window on top, right click on window titlebar, and choose `always on top`.

[image]